# Loading same component for multiple paths

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to load the Search component for all paths that have "/car/" in it.

In my index.js I have:

```
var indexRoutes = [

{ path: "/authentication", name: "Athentication", component: Blanklayout },
{ path: '/', name: 'Dashboard', component: Fulllayout }

];

ReactDOM.render(
<BrowserRouter>
<Switch>
  {indexRoutes.map((prop, key) => {
    return <Route path={prop.path} key={key} component={prop.component} />;
  })}
  <Route path="/car/" component={Search} />
</Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
,document.getElementById('root'));
```

When I navigate to /car/hello I'd expect this to load the Search component as I have the path /car/ specified but this doesn't work.

I have also tried using /car/* but still this doesn't work.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? Been scratching my head for the past couple of hours on this.

Comment: Does the `/car` path work as expected?

Comment: Also could you edit your post to show your `indexRoutes`?

Comment: @KenoClayton Added the indexRoutes. Also, going to /car doesn't load the expected component. Just a blank page

Comment: Assuming that `Search` has been imported, try removing the trailing slash for the path

Comment: @KenoClayton Even <Route path="/car" component={Search} /> doesn't load the Search component. And yes, the Search component has been imported

Comment: Is your app served from a subdirectory or just localhost root?

Comment: It works when I remove indexRoutes.map(){} however, this is something I need

Comment: Its served from a localhost root

Comment: It would seem as if the map function is causing the issue then, I'll quickly test it and see.

Comment: @KTOV Try using `exact` in map function route.  `<Route exact path={prop.path} key={key} component={prop.component} />;` The route for `path: '/'` is being used before it reaches the `/car` route.

Comment: I've got it working, but I had to use `exact` for the root path. Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/qz88xl6vk9

Comment: @KenoClayton the reason is that it stops rendering other routes once it finds the first matching one. Check [this](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Switch). You can also put the cars route in the indexRoutes.

Answer (score 0):

By default the `/` path is included in the rest of your routes, so you have to use `exact` to differentiate it from the rest.

```
var indexRoutes = [
  { path: "/", name: "Dashboard", component: Fulllayout, exact: true },
  { path: "/authentication", name: "Athentication", component: Blanklayout, exact: false }
];

...

indexRoutes.map((prop, key) => {
  return (
    <Route
      path={prop.path}
      key={key}
      component={prop.component}
      exact={prop.exact}
    />
  );
});
```